# Flask Form, keep values after submit

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I have a flask form that has some values for a given event. On submit I redirect the user to page where I take the values from the form and calculate some statistics about the event. The user can accept these values, and submit the event to the database, or click an edit button which will take them back to the form for them to modify the values. The issue is since the form has already been submitted, when they click edit and are redirected back to the form, all the values are gone. I want the values to stay because chances are they will only be modifying one or two fields and I don't want them to have to re-enter all of them. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any code. But why can't you store the values in the DB and load the values when you open the form? If the user wants to edit the values, you just update the values in the DB.

Or, can't you store the values in a global dictionary and just re-load it when you go back to the form if some values in the dictionary exist? Again, hard to say since you have no code sample but this is just some thoughts which you can think about.

Comment: @Payam thanks for the reply! Currently I am storing in a global dict, that just didn't seem like the cleanest way to do it. I'm new to flask so I didn't know if there was a clean way that the flask form could handle this. 

`if (current_user.username in current_app.config["current_form"] and request.method != "POST"):
    form = current_app.config["current_form"][current_user.username]
else:
    form = Form()`

Answer (score 1):

You can let Flask-wtf generate the form automatically, and it can remember the user input. If you pass the form instance to your Jinja template like this:

```
form = SomeForm()
return render_template("template.html", form=form)
```

A minimal example of a form:

```
class SomeForm(FlaskForm):
    name = TextField(label='name', default="")
    save = SubmitField(label='Save', description="Save")
```

And in your Jinja template:

```
<form method="post" action="the url" class="form-inline">
    <ul>
        {% for field in form %}
        <li>{{ field.label }} {{ field }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.history.back();`.

From [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API):  "This acts exactly as if the user clicked on the Back button in their browser toolbar"

This works because the browser saves the users inputs , all except for the `type="password"` ones